# Dynamically naming my dragula instance

Tags: angular

In my page.ts file I have this line where I define the value of tableID:

```
this.tableID = navParams.data.tableID
```

In my template I am using Dragula for drag and drop.

```
<ion-col col-12 class="active-players" id="active-section" [dragula]="drop">
```

I would like change drop to be drop-tableID, for example drop-1, drop-2, etc

I have tried ..

```
<ion-col col-12 class="active-players" id="active-section" [dragula]="drop-{{ tableID }}">
```

But this seems to break my app as I just see a white page, no errors in the console though.

What's the correct syntax to be able to dynamically name my dragula instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try one of these options:

```html
dragula="drop-{{ tableID }}"

[dragula]="'drop-' + tableID"

bind-dragula="'drop-' + tableID"
```

Comment: That's great. The second option worked a treat. Thank you.